# How do I combine 2 functions and only have one run if the other has no options selected

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to run a function which is using a featured image as my header image on my webpage I want to include the options to also allow my end user to select between using the featured image or to select a slider instead if they wish to use that page depending here is the code I have for the featured image development.

```
add_action('neve_before_primary', 'getPageFeaturedImage', 5);
function getPageFeaturedImage() {
//  These two variables will only be used if set
    $pageTitle = get_field('page-title');
    $pageSecondTitle = get_field('page_second_title');

    if (has_post_thumbnail($post -> ID) ) {
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post -> ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail');
        

            <div class="featured-image-container">
                <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" class="featured-image">
            </div>

    </div>
```

This code when run is making the feadured image the main image on the page with a title container on top of it with some css which doesnt matter for this question below you will find the code I have for the slider.

```
function smartsliderheader() {
echo '<div class="smart-slider-header">';
$slider = get_field("smart_slider_header"); 
echo do_shortcode($slider); 
}
```

This on its own does what I need it to do the featured image code works and so does the slider but getting them both to run toghether and have only one of them run if the other has no options used is where I could used some help.

Any help with this will be much apprechiated. I look forward to your questions if I have missed something out.

Comment: your first function is not valid. Please create a minimal reproducable example so we can help you out. Also I do not understand what you mean with "getting them both to run toghether and have only one of them run if the other has no options used" What options?

Comment: @FUZIION im not sure I follow when you say the first function it not valid if you could explain this it would be appreciated. The entire function is actually the minimal reproduction of the code however I will try to slim this down to assist in the assistance being provided. as for "getting them both to run together and have only one of them run if the other has no options used" what I mean by this as put in the tags of the post these run via ACF so by using IF and ELSE I can make one of them run if the other has no fields selected via its option in the editor made available via ACF.

Comment: so when the user selects a featured image and does not select a slider it will display the featured image. however if the user selects a slider it will display a slider and not a featured image. both of the single areas of code run fine on there own this is a case of getting them to work in a IF and ELSE as I cant seem to get that working with the code I provided.

Comment: @FUZIION the first function has now been simmered down to its simplest state.

Comment: What's the logic behind "user to select between using the featured image or to select a slider instead if they wish"? How do you recognize if someone selected one or the other?

Comment: @Diego by using the first snippet in the answer I posted it will check for values for the variables set in $slider and or $checkFeaturedImage this checks for a value and if either has a value the code will display that data if both have values it defaults back to the original which is the slider in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to solve this by myself by doing the following code we are using 2 variables one is for a featured image and the other is go a slider please look below for the code and an explanation.

```
if(!$checkFeaturedImage and !$slider) { 
return null ; 
}
```

This is checking to see if either of these variable's have a value assigned to them e.g. if a featured image is selected a value will be assigned to it and vice versa for a slider what this is doing if neither of these have a value it will stop the rest of the function running and save render time on the site.

```
if ($slider) {
echo '<div class="header-featured-image">' ; 
echo do_shortcode($slider); 
echo '</div>' ;

}
```

What this is doing is it is making a call to an advanced custom field set up to allow a slider to be selected and if a value is returned that value is then being directly echoed out onto the page.

```
else {
        if (has_post_thumbnail($post -> ID) ) {
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post -> ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail'); }
        ?>
            <div class="header-featured-image"> 
                <div class="featured-image-container">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" class="featured-image">
                </div>
            </div>
        }
<?php
    }
```

What this is doing is this is displaying our featured image onto our page if a value is returned by our page editor.

The way this code has been set up is if a featured image and a slider have both been selected it will default back to a slider as that is the first call and due to the null statement at the beginning if nothing is selected nothing will run saving some rendering time.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do this using an if statement checking if the `$pageTitle` and the `$pageSecondTitle` are empty

```
if(empty($pageTitle) && empty($pageSecondTitle)) {
    // do stuff for when settings aren't filled in
}
else {
    // do stuff for when settings are filled in.
}
```

I don't know if this answers your question. Let me know if this goes into the direction you want to go so I can build on it further.

Comment: thank you for your help but I was actually able to fix this on my own however thank you for your help!

Comment: thank you for your assistance anyway I have awarded you the bounty so it doesn't go to waste :)

Comment: Thank you! Glad You found the solution